# Eclipse: why is ant build launched for one project when I start debug cfg for another?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ant, build

I have two Java projects loaded in Eclipse both of which include `build.xml` files. I created a debug configuration for `projectA` but when I launch it (`right click -> Debug As -> Debug configurations -> etc`) before it starts, `ant` build for `projectB` runs. Something in my environment is out of whack, and I am sure it's my fault, but I can't figure out how to stop this. Please help!

By the way, in case it matters, the `build.xml` for `projectA` is currently incomplete, i.e. I can't use it to run a meaningful build of that project.

Comment: Can you post what you see in the debug configurations view when your debug configuration is selected?  Also, double check to make sure you don't have an `ant builder` setup in the `builders` section of the properties of the project (right click project -> properties -> builders).  This could cause it to run the ant build every time you build the project.

Comment: @randal4 Indeed, I somehow had the ant builder for `projectB` listed as a builder for `projectA`. Removing it fixed the problem. Thanks so much!